# Is there any way to distinguish between two templatetags that have the same name?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 2 different template tags that share the same name: the_template_tag.

Is there any way to distinguish between the two template tags? Something like "source1.the_template_tag" and "source2.the_template_tag"?

Here is my case. I am using [django-timezones](https://github.com/brosner/django-timezones). There is a templatetag called localtime that basically allows me to display the date in the client local time.

```
{% load timezone_filters %}
... some more code
"user_localtime": "{{ serverdate|localtime:user_timezone }}",
```

Also, I am using the new timezones of Django 1.4. When I need to use the client local time (with the [django-timezone](https://github.com/brosner/django-timezones)), then I start to have problems. Basically, I have to turn off the timezones of django:

```
{% load tz %}
... some more code
{% localtime off %}
```

But the templatetag is the same. Then, of course, I get an error when I try to use both:

```
{% load tz %}
{% load timezone_filters %}
... some more code
{% localtime off %}
"user_localtime": "{{ serverdate|localtime:user.user_timezone }}",
```

Comment: I reverted your question back to the original version. After accepting an answer you shouldn't change the question - especially since your new question is completely different. You should ask a new question and can refer to this one in it as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Stop using django-timezones and use the timezone features of django 1.4
2. If you must use django-timezones, edit the source and rename the tag.

I would highly recommend #1, and strongly discourage #2.

Comment: Thanks Burhan. I tried the first one but the problem I have is that the date is always displayed with the server timezone. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the way I "localize" the date top the client timezone. I will research on this.

Comment: Make sure you go over the [timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) docs. For one, it needs to be enabled.

Comment: I got it now. I had to activate the timezone with [timezone.activate(client_timezone)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone). My error was trying to use functions like [astimezone](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to convert to client timezone.

Comment: I need to totally refactor this question because the solution was very different to the question. Is that ok?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question after you have accepted an answer, just create a new question.

Comment: But I edited the question first and, just then, accepted the answer. Now, you edited it again. What should I do? I don't want to mislead people with the current question and an unrelated solution.

Comment: Simply ask a new question and link back to this one.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. The problem that I see is that the reply does not answer the question. So, the question is misleading. I don't see how a new question is going to fix that. On the other hand, I just accepted the answer after modifying the question. So "undo" the last edit would solve the problem.